# PHP difference between shuffle and array_rand

Tags: php

What exactly is the difference between `shuffle` and `array_rand` functions in PHP? Which is faster if there is no difference.

Thanks

Comment: +1: welcome and good question, never paid attention to that...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When called on an array, **[`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/shuffle) randomizes the order of all elements of that array**.

For example, the following portion of code :

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
shuffle($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Could give this output :

```
array
  0 => int 3
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 5
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 2
```

The whole array itself gets modified.

When called on an array, **[`array_rand`][2] returns one or more keys from that array, randomly selected**.

For example, the following portion of code :

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$randomly_selected = array_rand($arr, 3);
var_dump($randomly_selected);
```

Could give tis kind of output :

```
array
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
```

A sub-array of the initial array is returned -- and the initial array is not modified.

Comment: Note that array_rand returns array keys, not the elements themselves.

Answer (score 4):

`shuffle` re-orders an array in a random order. **this function takes an array by reference, because it is mutating the internal structure of the array, not only accessing it**, while `array_rand` simply returns a random index in an array.

Answer (score 2):

`shuffle` affects the array keys and uses its parameter by reference.  `shuffle` used to be weak in terms of randomization in older versions of PHP but that is no longer true.

`array_rand` leaves the original array intact and has an optional parameter to allow you to select the number of elements you wish to return.

Answer (score 2):

`Shuffle()` takes the entire array and randomises the position of the elements in it. [Note: In earlier versions of PHP the shuffle() algorithm was quite poor]

`array_rand()` takes an array and returns one or more randomly selected entries. The advantage to array_rand() is that it leaves the original array intact.

Answer (score 2):

By changing **$no** parameter I tried following code snippet to test performances of both function. Even in big arrays there is no much differrence. Most of the the time between 1x10<sup>-5</sup> seconds and 5x10<sup>-5</sup>

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
$rand_keys = array_rand($myArray, $no);
echo (microtime(true)-$time_start)."\n";

$time_start = microtime(true);
shuffle($myArray);
echo (microtime(true)-$time_start)."\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

`shuffle` changes the order of an array's elements. It's a sorting function.

`array_rand` returns `n` (arguments[1], defaults to 1) random elements from the array. It returns a key (for arguments[1] == 1) or an array of keys (for arguments[1] > 1) which reference the elements of the array (arguments[0]).